# Android : After getting response from database its go back to previous screen

Tags: android, json, listview

Can any one help me..?? My problem is that, after getting response from json [its coming from webservice, in that there is Select query to fetch records], instead of display in listview its go back to previous screen Here is my sample code for that..

```
public class MainActivity5 extends ListActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        phNumber = i.getStringExtra("phn_no");

        new SearchCustomer().execute();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, customerList, R.layout.activity_main5, new String[] { TAG_F_NAME, TAG_C_PHONE }, new int[] { R.id.TextViewName, R.id.TextViewPhone });
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    class SearchCustomer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private boolean successFlag;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity5.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Searching Customer..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            String inputPhnNoText = phNumber;

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phno", inputPhnNoText));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_search_customer, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Search Response", json.toString());

            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    successFlag = true;
                    result = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULT);
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String fname = c.getString(TAG_F_NAME);
                        String phoneNumber = c.getString(TAG_C_PHONE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_F_NAME, fname);
                        map.put(TAG_C_PHONE, phoneNumber);
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        customerList.add(map);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    successFlag = false;
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            pDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my activity file code.. in doinbackground customerList I got the exact data what I want, but problem is that its not stay in the custom_list_view screen its go back to previous screen where a textbox and search button are there.. so not able to show record...

Everybody please, can any one give solution to this silly thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Agree with CapDroid regarding finish(), don't do it.
2. Don't call create adapter and set adapter inside `onCreate()`, instead you can do it inside `onPostExecute()`.
3. You are doing 2 overheads, Don't do those.

For example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String fname = c.getString(TAG_F_NAME);
                        String phoneNumber = c.getString(TAG_C_PHONE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_F_NAME, fname);
                        map.put(TAG_C_PHONE, phoneNumber);
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        customerList.add(map);
                    }
```

No need to do this kind of overhead, instead you can create a custom adapter by extending **`ArrayAdapter<JSONObject>`** so you don't need to prepare `HashMap`, instead you can add `JSONObject` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `finish()` from onPostExecute in your code.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, customerList, R.layout.activity_main5, new String[] { TAG_F_NAME, TAG_C_PHONE }, new int[] { R.id.TextViewName, R.id.TextViewPhone });
        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Comment: Hi Chirag and CapDroid.. 

Thanks for that, to notify me.. its no go back to previous screen atleast.. but problem is still remain data is not showing in this screen.. and in logcat i found the response like this ::

{"result":[{"customer_lname":"last name","customer_fname":"first name","customer_id":"1","customer_phone":"1111100000"}],"success":1}

Screen is blank.. so can you help more..??

Answer (score 1):

Your

> finish()

method close your activity so remove this.

Comment: @Chirag Raval & Me did same answer so you should Up Vote instead of same answer

Answer (score 0):

Don't finish activity in `onPostExecute()` method.

Comment: @Chirag Raval & Me did same answer so you should Up Vote instead of same answer

Comment: @CapDroid you should also do the same.

Comment: I am doing same.. you can check time I did first answer of all